# space constrained, cost constrained; super capacitor UPS decision paralysis

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, supercapacitor, ups, power-management

I am currently in the process of evaluation of options regarding Super capacitor UPS designs.

The requirements are simple, find the most effective solution to keep alive 5V supply line for ~20 seconds.

The initial expected current is around 2.5A, decreasing after around 10s to 1A.

I've looked on existing designs, especially the wide range of Raspberry UPS products and I find them all over complicated and unnecessarily expensive. (Maybe I am the one who's wrong and oversimplified solution just can't be designed)

State your opinion which one of these solutions seems to be the most viable to you, alternatively, state what issues might prevent the UPS designs from working correctly.

Here are solutions that I've shortlisted so far:

1. Using hyper integrated solution from Advanced Linear: LTC4041 (charging, balancing, switchover, overvoltage...)

Although this solution is probably the most technically correct, I find the price outrageous and I would have to sacrifice other functionalities to fit this design within budget.

Approximate BOM: ~5$ (not counting the supercap)

2. Using Two Supercaps in series, charging via efuse, with pass-trough step up converter

[image: option 2]

The efuse function is just to slowly ramp up the voltage so that the super cap can charge correctly and not cause inrush current spike. Additionally, the load is turned on after the charging process is over. The ultra slow rise might mess up the power sequencing thats happening down the line.
The problem is that the 1uH inductor might cause interferences with the load and cause power loss during normal operation.

Approximate BOM: ~0.8$ (not counting the supercap)

3. Option with stacked super capacitors

[image: option 3]

Using single supercap charged via abused step down (using internal short circuit protection as constant current source, Power good as "done charging" signal) with pass-trough step up converter and ideal diode.

Honestly, I am not quite sure if my barbaric approach to constant current dc-dc will work. The controller could just latch off the entire circuit, or it might be harmful in the long term. Someone more experienced, state your opinion.

To explain what the "ST" of ideal diode does: basically, if it is conducting, it shuts down the buck converter to prevent the current form looping back to the supercap.

Approximate BOM: ~0.5$ (not counting the supercap)

Datasheets:

Ideal diode: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm66100.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-mousermode-df-pf-null-wwe&DCM=yes&distId=26

step down: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv62568a.pdf?ts=1590506250082

step up: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61022.pdf?ts=1590506435590

Comment: You are describing hold up (at least from an avionics perspective); the term UPS has a lot of baggage. You will need to specify the load current. https://www.atrenne.com/assets/pdf/ACS-WP-HOLDUP2-610318Csmall.pdf

Comment: Good point, I edited it in the post: The initial expected current is around 2.5A, decreasing after around 10s to 1A; and I've never heard the term hold up, thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Why would load current begin at 2.5 amps and fall to 1 amp after 10 seconds. A UPS provides a seemless changeover from one supply to the other and you cannot therefore say that the load changes by so much. The implication of what you are saying is that after ten seconds the load current begins again at 2.5 amps falling back over ten seconds and then continues to repeat. Please confirm.

Comment: Are you ok with the fact that you might need, say, 50 farads of capacitance to make this work?

Comment: When the device looses main power, it needs to broadcast some data, therefore, the load is around 2.5A.  After around 10 seconds, the wireless communication is over and the transmitter is turned off, which reduces the load down to 1A. The following 10 seconds is for the computer system to safely shut down, after that, no power is drawn from the UPS.

Comment: For solution #3, your ideal diode cannot supply 2.5A for 10s - Absolute Max ratings say <120ms for 2.5A. A quick Digikey search suggests your BOM cost might go up to several dollars if you want to stick with a >2.5A internal-switch ideal diode

Comment: This sounds like homework to me. Is it?